# Is it good or bad to have a weight lifting increase of at least 40-50 lbs on max Squat and RDL in a month?

Tags: weightlifting

hi I just started working out a month ago and was wondering what the gains I should be expecting. I only go for an hr or so every day to every other day and was just curious on what everyone's thoughts are. I've had 4 knee cap dislocations as well as knee surgery repairing cartilage as well. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to ignore the knee issues because a) I'm not a doctor, and b) they're unrelated to the question you're actually asking (though if you're concerned, go talk to a sports specific medical professional about it).

What you're experiencing are commonly referred to as "newbie gains", as in, as a person new to working out, you're finding that the amount of weight you can lift rapidly increases as you get more comfortable under the bar / handling the weight, your technique improves and you build a better mind-muscle connection (i.e. you learn how to recruit muscles better).

Make the most of them while you can, but try and not go crazy and injure yourself. You'll find at some point the amount you add to the bar session to session will drop off until you're making either very small gains or seemingly plateauing. This is what's commonly referred to as "the grind".

This is the point where most people quit. Don't be most people.

When you hit this point, recognise it for what it is and make sure your diet and recovery and on point, then do what you can to push through. You may need to mix up your training a little, you may just need a week off, but that's a question for another time.